Each elements in Locally finite precompact open cover of a topological manifold has at most finite intersection with others
The problem is from John M Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifold:problem 1.4.(see below image)

I have checked similar post regarding this problem from elsewhere of this site. However, I still find it confusing from the wording of "finite intersection with others".
I understand the arguement is that for each $U \in \mathcal{U}$ ,using $\hspace{3pt}$ $\mathcal{\overline{U}}:= \{\overline{U} | U \in \mathcal{U}\}$ is locally finite ,apply compactness proerty and we can obtain the finite subcover of  $U$.
The concern I have here is, the finite subcovers are not necessarily the only elements that intersecting $U$. However, I dont know how to prove such stronger assertion i.e. for each $U \in \mathcal{U} $, there exist at most $U_1,...,U_n$ that are intersecting $U$...
My first thought is since $\cap_{U \in \mathcal{U}} U = \emptyset$, then we have finite subcollection $\cap_{i=1}^n U_i = \emptyset$. But it seems leading no where...
Any help will be appreciated

Do you only have trouble with part c?

Yes, the others are quite straightforward

So, I don't know what the official way to do it is, but here's my attempt (just for part c):
By contradiction, assume $U \in \mathcal{U}$ intersects infinitely many sets in $\mathcal{U}$, but $\mathcal{U}$ is locally finite. Now, $\overline{U}$ is compact, and by local finiteness we can find a finite open cover of $\overline{U}$ (and thus of $U$) such that each element only intersects finitely many elements of $\mathcal{U}$. If $U_1,\ldots,U_n$ is such a cover, and $n$ is minimal, then we have that if $n$ is one then $U_1 \supset U$, a contradiction, and if $n > 1$, then for any $V \in \mathcal{U}$, $(U_1 \cup U_2) \cap V = (U_1 \cap V) \cup (U_2 \cap V)$, thus $U_1 \cup U_2, U_3,\ldots,U_n$ is also a valid cover, contradicting the minimality of $n$.

I am not sure if I understand your argument, but now I see that you use compactness to claim that $U$ only intersects finite many covers. However, compactness does not have such strong implications. For example a unit ball can be covered by any balls with any radius. However, it is clear to see that the fintie subcover are not the only elements that cover the unit ball.

And using the words in your proof, I believe what you should make sure is the maximal number of $n$ is finite instead of the minimal ones.

@mikeqwertyuiop You would be correct if I didn't also assume locally finiteness. Because of local finiteness, I can cover $U$ with open sets that onli intersect finitely many elements of $\mathcal{U}$, and then pick a finite subcover. In my proof I then argue essentially by induction that the union of that finite subcover only interects finitely elements in $\mathcal{U}$.

Yes i can see it now, thanks for the help!

@mikeqwertyuiop I have a bad habit of overcompactifying my proofs leading to some confusion lol. Glad I've been able to clear it up :)

This is my attempt:
First, we know that $\mathcal{\overline{U}}$ is locally finite as well. For each $x \in \overline{U} \in \overline{\mathcal{U}}$, there exist a open neighborhood $N_x$
of $x$ such that $N_x$ only intersects $U_{1}^x ,..., U_{n}^x$.
Using compactness, $U$ has a finite subcover $\cup_{i=1}^n N_i$. Suppose each $N_i$ is intersecting at most  $U_{i_1} ,..., U_{i_n}$. Gather these $U_{i_k}$'s from each $N_i$ and relabel them as $\cup_{j=1}^m U_j$.
Claim: $U$ only intersects $\cup_{j=1}^m U_j$ and itself
Proof: Suppose $V \in \mathcal{U}$ and $V \neq U, U_j$. If there exist $x \in V \cap U$, then first we know $x \in N_i$ for some $i$ and by $V \cap U$ is open, we have a open neighborhood $B$ that $x \in B \subset V \cap N_i \cap U $. However, such intersection has to be empty by the assumption that $N_i$ does not intersect $V$. This proves that $V \cap U =\emptyset$.
Therefore $U$ only intersect finitely many elements in $\mathcal{U}$.
I think the argument are extremely similar, and it is not hard to believe that some people can see through the result without explicitly writing it out.

I don't think this quite works: how can we suppose each $N_i$ (which I assume are just arbitrary neighborhoods of points in $U$) intersects only finitely many of elements in $\mathcal U$? You're right that the (pre)compactness of $U$ guarantees it has a finite subcover (wrt any open cover), but we don't have the property that any neighborhood (i.e. the $N_i$) intersect finitely many $U_i$; that's even stronger than what we're trying to prove!

Is months ago so i might wrong, but base on what I have written here, i am only using the locally finite property to claim there exists such neighbourhoods $N_i$
